# Invoke method from unknown class

Tags: c#, generics

It's possible to Invoke a method from unknown a class?

```
public class ClientSampleResponse : IPacket
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public void Execute<T>(T client)
    {
        var method = typeof(T).GetMethod("Send");
        //method.Invoke(this);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to Invoke this method from unknown class using the above code:

```
public void Send<T>(T packet) where T : IPacket
{
    // Skip contents
}
```

Comment: Can I have any explanations why its should be down voted?

Comment: Why it got downgrade? Any by who?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, and your code looks fine. What problem are you facing?

Comment: @Heinzi Yes, that's what I thought too. but the `method.Invoke(this)` is not allowed in the compiler.

Comment: @LeonelSarmiento: Where is the instance of your unknown class? Or do you want to create a new one? (`Activator.CreateInstance` will help here.)

Comment: Note: The correct syntax for Invoke is: `method.Invoke(instanceOfYourUnknownClass, parameter)`.

Comment: if Send is not a static method the first parameter of `Invoke` should be a reference to an instance of the class with the Send method. (client I suppose: `method.Invoke(client, this);`
if it's a static method, you can call it with passing `null` as first parameter: `method.Invoke(null, this);` see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Heinzi I tried this `method.Invoke(client, this);` but the problem here it the `ClientSampleRespose` can't convert into object.

Comment: can not convert into object[], that is the issue, you have to put it into new object[] {this}

Comment: @GianPaolo yes, that's what I expect too, but the compiler will throw the exception  `Argument 2: cannot convert from 'ClientPackets.ClientSampleResponse' to 'object[]'`.

Comment: @ipavlu Nice!, I din't realize that one.

Comment: by the way, you know that your T will have a Send Method: are you sure you cannot force a constraint such `where T: ISender` or `where T: Sender`? if so, you can avoid both generics and reflection
See [this filddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QLsCaM)

Comment: @GianPaolo I can't because they where in different projects, and they can't reference each other because it will throw an circular dependency.

Comment: @LeonelSarmiento so create a third library where you define the ISender interface, and reference this library from both projects. This will help you decoupling code, which is always a good thing

Comment: @GianPaolo But It will give me a problem when Deserializing  the object from the memory-stream?

Comment: @LeonelSarmiento, I don't think you will have such problems, but without see the full code it's hard to tell. Also, I thing you will deserialize a `ClientSampleResponse` on the "other side" of the system (is Sender a socket? what else?) so actually it should not depend in any way on the Sender of ISender interface. Consider also removing the `Execute` method from the ClientSampleResponse`, and move it somewhere else: why something you send over the network (as a bunch of data, I assume) should also have an "Execute" method? are you expecting to call the same method on the other side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
public void Execute<T>(T client)
{
    var method = typeof(T).GetMethod("Send");
    method.Invoke(client, new object[] { this });
}
```

Also, be sure that your object client, doesn't possess several Send methods, otherwise you should consider using `GetMethod("Send", new Type[] { typeof(IPacket) })`.
[Documentation: GetMethod(string name, Type[] types)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/6hy0h0z1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke any method of any object as long as the method exists as explain [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx).

I find the code example pretty clear:

```
   // Get the constructor and create an instance of MagicClass

        Type magicType = Type.GetType("MagicClass");
        ConstructorInfo magicConstructor = magicType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
        object magicClassObject = magicConstructor.Invoke(new object[]{});

        // Get the ItsMagic method and invoke with a parameter value of 100

        MethodInfo magicMethod = magicType.GetMethod("ItsMagic");
        object magicValue = magicMethod.Invoke(magicClassObject, new object[]{100});
```

Did I miss Something?

Answer (score 1):

YOu need to call Invoke(client, this) not Invoke(this), as this is of ClientSampleResponse, IPacket not related to T.

```
public class ClientSampleResponse : IPacket
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Lastname { get; set; }
   public string Address { get; set; }
   public void Execute<T>(T client)
   {
       var method = typeof(T).GetMethod("Send");
       method.Invoke(client, new object[] { this });
   }
```

}

and yeah, parameters are sent as array